# read single words in the middle of a file

Tags: c, file, io

I need to make a program that take in input a .db file like that:

```
Boston 685463 2413
Cleveland 781221 3890
Chicago 468923 2781
LosAngeles 618292 1902
NewYork 38723 567
```

where the first set of numbers is the number of voters in elections and the second one is the number of white boards.

The user can insert three kind of inputs:

```
./program CityName
./program voters
./program white
```

the first input must print something like that:

```
./program Boston
Boston 685463 2413
```

the second one must print the total number of voters and the third one prints the total number of white borards.

how can I take the single words or number sets from the file to do that?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a "write my program for me" service.

Comment: I don't want anyone to tell me how to write the program, I only want to know how manipulate the single words of the file into the program.

Comment: What do you mean by that? What have you tried? Which part of the task are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the file line by line using `fscanf` (you need a string and two numbers (long/int/etc depends on the required size of the numbers))

On each iteration check if one of the three values matches your query. If so, print the result and `break` the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You could make an array of structures that contain name of city, first and second number and then search through it using bsearch (if it is sorted by name, seems to me like it is) and after that just print data from found structure.